# Saving list of lists into another list of list but with changes in python

Tags: python, list

i have a list like this one :

```
list1= [['Sarah', 55, 7, 'x'], ['John', 24, 8, 'x']]
```

and i want to copy it to another list but keeping it as a matrix like that :

```
list2= [['Sarah', 55.0, 7.0], ['John', 24.0, 8.0]]
```

so what i want to do is making every number a float and deleting the last element of every sub-list

Comment: Can we help with your code? Please share it by editing your question.

Comment: Two upvotes for a user who didn't even share an attempt... really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [['Sarah', 55, 7, 'x'], ['John', 24, 8, 'x']]

list2 = [[] for x in range(len(list1))]

x = 0

for rp in range(len(list1)):
    #len(list1[rp])-1 for not count the last element for each array 
    for tp in range(len(list1[rp])-1):
        #check the type of item string
        if "str" in str(type(list1[rp][tp])):
            list2[x].append(list1[rp][tp])
        #check the type of item int
        elif "int" in str(type(list1[rp][tp])):
            #convert the item int to float
            td = float(list1[rp][tp])
            list2[x].append(td)

    x += 1

print("List 1 :" + str(list1))
print("List 2 :" + str(list2))

#OUTPUT
#List 1 :[['Sarah', 55, 7, 'x'], ['John', 24, 8, 'x']]
#List 2 :[['Sarah', 55.0, 7.0], ['John', 24.0, 8.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested list comprehension, casting  to `float` all strings that satisfy `str.isnumeric`:

```
[[float(j) if str(j).isnumeric() else j for j in i] for *i, _ in list1]
# [['Sarah', 55.0, 7.0], ['John', 24.0, 8.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension here:

```
[[name, *map(float, i)] for name, i, _ in list1]
```

Results:

```
[['Sarah', 55.0, 7.0], ['John', 24.0, 8.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use unpacking to make the conversion clearer:

```
list2 = [ [name,float(n1),float(n2)] for name,n1,n2,_ in list1 ]
```